# Is there a way to make a liquid cold by a chemical reaction?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, heat

I'm looking for a way to combine two substances in a chemical reaction that uses a lot of energy, therefore absorbing heat, to make a substance cold.

I'm thinking about a two-chamber thermos that in the middle chamber is, for example, juice and in the outside chamber will be placed the other substances. When these substances react, is it possible that they absorb heat, making the juice colder?

Comment: Not only possible - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_cold_pack

Answer (score 2):

Ammonium thiocyanate and barium hydroxide octahydrate when mixed will draw a huge quantity of heat. This reaction often used as a chemistry demo of endothermic reactions where the chemicals are mixed in a beaker that's placed on a wet piece of wood. The wood freezes to the beaker.